# How to make a similar color variants in android?

Tags: java, android, flood-fill

I want to make a similar color variant in android of the color chosen by the user.

Please refer to the image.In it when the use picks color from the color picker i want to display the same  color with little faded or lighter .[refer image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbs6o.png) 
For example wen user selects green color i want to show variants of green color.